# React native error window causing crash on iOS

Tags: ios, react-native

I integrated React Native in my existing iOS application, following the instructions on the official website.
It works most of the time, but when there is a Js error and it should display the React Native red error window, the app crashes instead.
I use RN 0.59

Is there something I'm missing ?

Here is my code to add React Native in my app:

View controller showing the RCTRootView:

```
class OnboardingViewController : UIViewController {
    var onboardingView: RCTRootView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.onboardingView = ReactNativeBridge.instance.viewForModule("Onboarding", initialProperties: ["locale" : "language_http_key".localize()])
        self.onboardingView.backgroundColor = UIColor.bbgBrandGreenColor()
        self.view.addSubview(self.onboardingView)
        if ((self.onboardingView) != nil) {
            self.onboardingView.frame = self.view.bounds
        }
    }

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle : UIStatusBarStyle {
        return UIStatusBarStyle.lightContent
    }
}
```

ReactNativeBridge implementation:

```
class ReactNativeBridge: NSObject {
    static let instance = ReactNativeBridge()
    var bridge: RCTBridge?

    func createBridgeIfNeeded() -> RCTBridge {
        if bridge == nil {
            bridge = RCTBridge.init(delegate: self, launchOptions: nil)
        }
        return bridge!
    }

    func viewForModule(_ moduleName: String, initialProperties: [String : Any]?) -> RCTRootView {
        let viewBridge = createBridgeIfNeeded()
        let rootView: RCTRootView = RCTRootView(
            bridge: viewBridge,
            moduleName: moduleName,
            initialProperties: initialProperties)
        return rootView
    }
}

extension ReactNativeBridge: RCTBridgeDelegate {
    func sourceURL(for bridge: RCTBridge!) -> URL! {
        #if DEBUG
            return URL(string: "http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios")
        #else
            return Bundle.main.url(forResource: "main", withExtension: "jsbundle")
        #endif
    }
}
```

The crash log:

```
2019-04-30 10:09:30.173593+0200 MyApp[98998:6032042] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MyApp.AppDelegate window]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000076c5f0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010eeb26fb __exceptionPreprocess + 331
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010d8ccac5 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010eed0ab4 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   UIKitCore                           0x0000000112945c3d -[UIResponder doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 287
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010eeb71a1 ___forwarding___ + 769
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010eeb9238 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    6   React                               0x000000010bc6e3d8 -[RCTRedBoxWindow bottomSafeViewHeight] + 120
    7   React                               0x000000010bc6ca61 -[RCTRedBoxWindow initWithFrame:] + 625
    8   React                               0x000000010bc718d1 __55-[RCTRedBox showErrorMessage:withParsedStack:isUpdate:]_block_invoke + 497
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000110644d7f _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000110645db5 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000110653080 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1540
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ee198a9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ee13f56 __CFRunLoopRun + 2310
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ee13302 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 626
    15  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000115c682fe GSEventRunModal + 65
    16  UIKitCore                           0x0000000112919ba2 UIApplicationMain + 140
    17  MyApp                            0x000000010756f658 main + 72
    18  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001106ba541 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Did you got the solution for the above. Even I am facing repeatly crash on the same.

Comment: I've not used React Native for a while, but if I remember well, I never found the solution for this problem unfortunately :/

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this exact issue with the same stack trace and error.

If you look at the top line error message, it's complaining that the `window` attribute in `-[MyApp.AppDelegate window]` is an `unrecognized selector`, meaning that it doesn't exist in MyApp.AppDelegate.

From the stack trace you posted, you can see that the RCTRedBox class is trying to invoke that [here.](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/80e24834ba8c581157fb6c9f5d8b49301677c487/React/CoreModules/RCTRedBox.mm#L204)

**Solution:**
If you add a UIWindow `window` attribute to your AppDelegate class (`MyApp.AppDelegate` in your case), and set it equal to whatever your main window is (i.e. `[UIScreen mainScreen]` or something), it should stop throwing that error when trying to display the redbox screen.